# NSToolbar looks different in Leopard and Snow Leopard

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, osx-snow-leopard, osx-leopard, nstoolbar

I have a Cocoa app I'm working on and I get a different result in appearance for the **[NSToolbar](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSToolbar_Class/Reference/Reference.html)** I am using for the main window.

Specifically, I'm using a search field as the last **[NSToolbarItem](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSToolbarItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html)** and, whereas under Snow Leopard it is displayed correctly:
[image]

it is cut under Leopard:
[image]

Looking at those two versions it appears that the spaces I put between the items are not respected under Leopard. I also saw that sometimes, after I make some update at the toolbar in Interface Builder, these changes are not mirrored in the running application even under Snow. I have to drag the default bar from the customizing menu in order to see them.

**UPDATE**
The reason for the NSToolbar not always mirroring what is in the .nib file resides in the autosave mechanism that was enabled for me, as NSGod suggested.

What can be the cause of this misbehavior? 
Is there something about constraints, (minimum and maximum) sizes that I should have taken into account?
Feel free to point some documentation to me

**UPDATE 2**
Is there a way to programmatically introduce item and spaces into a NSToolbar or check the consistency (at run time) of those entered with Interface Builder?

Comment: I have a work for you regarding this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481858/tutorial-on-how-to-drag-and-drop-item-from-uitableview-to-uitableview... can you please contact me ?

Comment: In my opinion you're better off managing complex toolbars using the traditional NSToolbar delegate methods rather than constructing the toolbar in Interface Builder. You have a lot more control with the delegate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I do recall having a couple of oddities with search fields in `NSToolbar`s, I've never seen the behavior where the right side of it is cut off.

Are the `NSToolbarItem`s that are spaces the fixed one-unit space, or the flexible spaces?

> "I also saw that sometimes, after I
>   make some update at the toolbar in
>   Interface Builder, these changes are
>   not mirrored in the running
>   application even under Snow. I have to
>   drag the default bar from the
>   customizing menu in order to see them."

You need to keep in mind that if you've enabled user customization and autosave behavior in the toolbar, then when the user explicitly makes a change, it will be saved to user defaults. If you then re-arrange your toolbar in IB and run the app, it's possible that the configuration saved in user defaults is overriding the default configuration you've specified in the nib file.

What I usually do is during testing, delete the prefs file for my app so changes can't be overridden. (FWIW, I usually use an AppleScript saved as an application that I keep in my Dock. It just runs a `do shell script` command which deletes the prefs file. Being a GUI-oriented type of person, it's easier for me to just click it to have it run right before debugging. This version of the script asks for the prefs file to delete, though it can also be customized: http://www.markdouma.com/developer/DeleteAppPrefs.zip. If you've never run it before, you get the choose file dialog, and the chosen file is saved as an alias inside the actual AppleScript, so you're not asked again. You can drag the icon onto AppleScript Editor to take a look at the script or change it).

Anyway, then, if I'm going to release a new version of an app that uses a new toolbar layout, and want to prevent the config from being overridden, I'll change the toolbar's identifier (or autosave name) to something like "docToolbar2.0".

Comment: You are correct about the autosaving overwriting the default toolbar layout. The spaces I'm using are now all fixed (and there is no space between the search field and the segmented control) but someone before was flexible. From the screenshot under Leopard it seems as if there is a flexible space between the segmented control and the search field and the search field gets cut as if there is no space. Can the minimum dimension matter?