# TableView drag & drop functionality

Tags: ios, uitableview

Can anyone please provide me a sample for table view drag & drop functionality?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481858/tutorial-on-how-to-drag-and-drop-item-from-uitableview-to-uitableview

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you create a subclass of UITableView controller, uncomment the following methods (or just add them if you are implementing `UITableView` `delegate` and `dataSource` protocols in custom class):

```
// Override to support rearranging the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath
{
    // update your model
}

// Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
    return YES;
}
```

Now you just need an edit button to start editing mode (you can put it in viewDidLoad):

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
```

And inside that `tableView:moveRowAtIndexPath:toIndexPath:` method you should update your model by rearranging array or whatever is holding your data.

Answer (score 1):

is that you need to rearrange ? . If so check [this](http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/how-to-add-delete-data-from-tableview-in-iphone/) or if you need drag drop check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481858/tutorial-on-how-to-drag-and-drop-item-from-uitableview-to-uitableview)