# How to know index of sections in tableview iPad

Tags: ipad, uitableview, indexing, tableview, sections

Can anyone help me with this please?

I have 2 tables in the same view, the first one is a menu table and the second one is empty with a button in the nav bar to add new sections. So when you click the add button it adds a new section but empty. What I want to do is when you click a row in the first table it gets added in the second table in the section selected.

The problem is that I don't know how to select a section, I added a tap recognizer to the section with a view but I don't know how to know the index of that section. I tried adding a tag for the view in the header but if I have 2 sections the index of each one is 2, if I have 3 sections the index of the three sections is 3 =/.

Any ideas??
Thanks in advance XD

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is similar to one of the question posted on the site.

This is the link for it.

[Tutorial on How to drag and drop item from UITableView to UITableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481858/tutorial-on-how-to-drag-and-drop-item-from-uitableview-to-uitableview)

Let me know if you are still unclear.