# Moving Cell/Row from one UITableView to another

Tags: uitableview, xamarin.ios

Is it possible in monotouch to move/drag one cell of a `UITableView` to another with database connected into it?

The scenario is like selling an item that instead of clicking the cell i will move/drag it. 
If it is possible,how? if not, what are the other ways and how it can be done?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Move an item from a table to another table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10442031/move-an-item-from-a-table-to-another-table)

Comment: @poupou I have deleted it, bec. it has 2 questions and not clear and also this one is revised this one of that one.

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481858/tutorial-on-how-to-drag-and-drop-item-from-uitableview-to-uitableview