# UITableView - how to recognize if i drag a cell over a cell?

Tags: ios, uitableview, drag

I want to recognize when i select a cell and drag it over another cell.

Is there any example/ workaround for this?

My goal is to create an UITableView which allows me to merge two cells into one cell.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tutorial on How to drag and drop item from UITableView to UITableView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481858/tutorial-on-how-to-drag-and-drop-item-from-uitableview-to-uitableview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use UITableView delegates

to move rows

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

And To compare CGRects

```
self.tableView rectForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)
```

Then, I believe, create, insert new cell.

Comment: hm... I guess, it's not proper way to do it